# How to perform only javascript onClick and not PHP action on submitting a form

Tags: laravel-5

I am making a form through laravel in which I want to accept only future dates.I am validating the date via javascript and popping an alert when past date is entered but the problem is that after the alert it is going to form action url (that the form is submitted) even if the past date is entered. I want it to remain to that page itself. Please help.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func() {
  var aa = document.getElementById('in').value;
  var bb=new Date();
  var y=aa.slice(0,4);
  var m=aa.slice(5,7);
  var d=aa.slice(8,10);
  if((y>=bb.getFullYear() && m>=(bb.getMonth()+1) && d>=bb.getDate())!=1) {
    alert('Enter future date');
  }
}
</script>

<body>
  <form action="/submitted" method="post">
  <input id="in" type="date" name="sdate">
  <input type="submit" onClick="func()"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will you post a snippet with the problem code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "return false;" after the "alert();" command.

```
if((y>=bb.getFullYear() && m>=(bb.getMonth()+1) && d>=bb.getDate())!=1)
  {
      alert('Enter future date');
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: @itsayushbansal Please, mark this answer as the correct answer. Then other peoples will get correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Send data with ajax like this:

```
function func() {
  var aa = document.getElementById('in').value;
  var bb = new Date();
  var y = aa.slice(0, 4);
  var m = aa.slice(5, 7);
  var d = aa.slice(8, 10);
  if ((y >= bb.getFullYear() && m >= (bb.getMonth() + 1) && d >= bb.getDate()) != 1) {
    alert('Enter future date');
  } else {
    var dataString = {
      'date': aa
    };
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: "dateroute",
      type: "post",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Good job!');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In your routes.php you have to add 'dateroute':

```
Route::post('dateroute', array('as' => 'dateroute', 'uses' => 'DateController@dateroute'));
```

Your DateController.php like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Request;
use Input;
class DateController extends Controller {

    public function dateroute() {
        if (Request::ajax()) {
            $data = Input::all();
            //here are all datas from ajax datastring
        }
    }
}
```